# How to select from DropDownList in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

1.HttpWebRequest+HttpWebResponse for login then go to page "ex.asps" 
2.send HttpWebRequest(with select option from ddl)+HttpWebRespons    to save all info that i need to StreamReader.

1.I succeed i see all info all work
2.I see the dll(Id, all options,values,name) But i cant find out the way to select the right option i can see and save only first one,nut i need to go trow the all ddl select one by one and save the data.
Ex: Like ddl with 4 User and each one have they own data like (Age,ID...)
i can save only 1 user but i need to change ddl to get new data

This is my code

```
if (IsLogin)
                            {
          HttpWebResponse RedirectResponse = RedirectToUrl("https://services.test.com/Pages/Trans.aspx");

Stream streamResponse = RedirectResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
outString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

System.Collections.ArrayList strAccountList = GetListByID("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts");
for (int intAccountCount = 0; intAccountCount < strAccountList.Count; intAccountCount++)
          {
string[] strAcctList = strAccountList[intAccountCount].ToString().Split('\t');
string strAccountNumber = strAcctList[0];

PostString += "__EVENTVALIDATION=" + GetValueByID(LoginInfo, "__EVENTVALIDATION") + "&";
PostString += "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$AccountsDDL$ddlAccounts=" + strAccountNumber + "&";

HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://services.test.com/currentaccount/Pages/current.aspx");

    postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    postRequest.CookieContainer = _cookies;
    postRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    postRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
    postRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    postRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    postRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostString);
    postRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream newStream = postRequest.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    newStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)postRequest.GetResponse();
    outString = "";
    Stream streamResponseLoginForm = postResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamReadLoginForm = new StreamReader(streamResponseLoginForm);
    outString = streamReadLoginForm.ReadToEnd();//Here i can see that data is not changed


                                    if (outString == null)
                                    {
                                        LogOut();
                                    }

                                }
```

Comment: people please do not rise down my question because i know there is the way to pass some data to PostString  that will resolve this!!!

Comment: Your question is downgraded because it looks very messy. It's hard to dig through it. You should invest some effort and improve readability. Then it's more likely that people will read your question and give an answer.

Comment: My origin question look diffrent it dont sow the few lines  from top i try to edit it but in edit mode i see the full question but here i can't see the first 2 lines.....

Comment: Please study the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in order to improve your formatting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts")[0].selectedIndex = 0;//Here we select the index
__doPostBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts','') // here the postback
```